# Actions Builder account linking throwing unexpected response

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

I'm new to using the actions builder console. I'm trying to create an application called "test for reminder" and trying to use account linking to get user's email. I followed all the steps listed out on the account linking tutorial. However, when I trigger the action, I'm getting the following response: *"To use test for reminder, you’ll need an account with test for reminder. To create a new one for you, I’ll just need some info. If you want more details, say "Tell me more." So, can I ask Google for your name, email address, and profile picture?"*

I'm not sure where that response is being triggered and how to go past it. Is it unable to verify my google account? If the user is verified, I have an event handler which is supposed to trigger if the user is verified, but that is not happening either.

Any insights would be appreciated

Comment: Are you doing OAuth & Google Sign-In, or do you just want to use Google Sign-In alone?

Comment: I'm using only google sign in. For some reason, it is asking me to create an account (i'm not sure where it is being stored). After I say yes, it does create one and takes me to my webhook event handler. However, I'm unable to access the user email still. Below is my updated code: app.handle('email', async conv => {
  let payload = conv.headers.authorization;
  console.log("working here");
  const email = payload.email;
  console.log(email + "email")
  
});

Comment: I'm also getting a warning saying that "FIREBASE_CONFIG and GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variables are missing". If you can guide me on how I can save that information, that will be great as well!. Thank you

Comment: Where are you hosting your webhook?

Comment: Its with the inline editor on the actions builder portal

Comment: Then I'm not quite sure why those environment variables would not exist.

Comment: Do you have any insight into what is happening with accessing the emaila as well? I followed the steps on the account linking tutorial, but it still can't access the email. Its saying that it is undefined. My code in in the comments above. Thanks

Comment: Are you 'VERIFIED' or a 'GUEST'

Comment: I'm verified, as I'm able to reach to my webhook. But, it can't access my email there

Comment: And you've properly set the `CLIENT_ID` as stated in the [profile info](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/google-sign-in#access_profile_information_in_your_backend) section of the docs?

Comment: Yes, this is how I have it set    const app = conversation({
  clientID : "my client id",
});